# positioning sticky field using hook_form_alter in drupal 7

Tags: 7, forms, hooks

I'm trying to remove the sticky option from the option bar and adding it to the user form.

```
function vacancies_form_vacature_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
// remove sticky field from default (option) location
unset($form['options']['sticky']);

//create new sticky field
$form['sticky'] = array (
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => 'Top vacature',
    '#default_value' => $form['#node']->sticky,
    '#weight' => -1,
);

dsm($form);
```

}

Weight of other elements go from `1` to `14` so `-1` should put this form element on top.
But with the code above it shows up at the end of the form.

How do I put the sticky button in the middle of my form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
$form['sticky'] = array (
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => 'Top vacature',
    '#default_value' => $form['#node']->sticky,
    '#weight' => -100,
);
```

works for me just fine. I don't know what's happening in your node edit form, but for me title field had #weight equal to -5, so obviously this item with weight -1 wouldn't show up on top.

Comment: as posted in my question my other elements have weight of 1 to 14 so -1 would be on top. Also note that I'm just putting it on top because I want to include it in the form and using an 'extreme' value (-1) to move it around.

Comment: What I just thought of is that there might be another implementation of hook_form_alter that changes fields weights running after your own hook_form_alter. So when your hook_form_alter is executed the weights of the fields are from 1 to 7 but they might be changed later.

I would suggest you to check if it is the case.

You can control the order in which hooks are called by setting module weight in system table.

Comment: good idea, I'll set the weight to -100 then to see if that changes anything.